# How to custom image using Image::make

Tags: php, laravel

In this project I've trying save the image in default path and after, custom imagens in another paths but I get this error

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException
Image source not readable
```

My version of Laravel is 6 and set too class in app.php

```
'aliases' => [

    // 'Image' => Folklore\Image\Facades\Image::class,

    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

    'ImageResize' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

],
'providers' => [

    // 'Image' => Folklore\Image\Facades\Image::class,

    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

    'ImageResize' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,

],
```

and in my controller I have the following code

```
use ImageResize;
use Image;


$imageName = '12768475_g.jpg';
$pathDefault = Storage::url('public/images/default/' . $imageName);

$imgageThumbnail = Image::make($pathDefault, array(
        'width' => 380,
        'height' => 380,
        'greyscale' => true,
        'center' => true
))->save('storage/images/thumbnail/' . $imageName);
```

Comment: What is `$name`?

Comment: @miken32 I'm sorry, edited ....

Answer (score 0):

```
      $image = $request->file('image');
    $slug = str_slug($request->title);
    if (isset($image))
    {
        $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
        $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());   
        $image_resize->resize(1600,1066);
        if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/post'))
        {
            mkdir('storage/uploads/post',0777,true);
        }
        $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/post/'.$imagename);
    }else{
        $imagename = "default.png";
    }
'aliases' => [

    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class

],
'providers' => [

    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class

],
```

Comment: thansk for your help, but I don't get image from form, I'm get external link for ex: http://imgimob.sobressai.com.br/fotos/765/475099/12768475_g.jpg, so I don't using request->file

Comment: first I get image from external link, so save in local project using Storage after copy this image to another path